# how to edit html using the webbrowser control? (turn on WYSIWYG features)

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

Similar to a WYSIWYG(What you see is what you get) editor
I want the user to be able to visually edit the html document and move objects around. How can I turn on these html editing features for the web browser control?

The environment I have is Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 64-bit.

> I want to enable the html editing features of the web browser control
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Note: the code for the web browser control being is being used in a specialized editor and is too large and numerous to post here but I can post a link to it later if anyone wants the full source. This is a large project please refer to here as I attempted to converse and search google before posting their or here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e5acdb2-9366-4258-890a-86eaaa1086ee/html-expert-needed.

Comment: Are you saying you want to create an HTML WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: if this is still unclear please post any problems you have with it.

Comment: I edited my question above to improve it and make it sound less vague. I needed to create an HTML WYSIWYG editor but their was a function I was looking for to turn on those features in the web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser control has a built-in [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) mini-[HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) editor. You can use it.
Here's an example to how to turn that edit mode on:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' I do this for this example, so that we have some elements loaded. 
    ' For you, you will need to add the tags from your code for various HTML elements.
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    ' To turn On the edit mode.
    Dim axObj As New Object
    axObj = WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance
    axObj.document.designmode = "On"
End Sub
```

Comment: Although that might work too for my project. To bad multiple answers cannot be marked because I would mark yours too.

Comment: I tryed this out very impressive knowledge bit. I will have to keep that treasure tucked away somewhere for future use.

Comment: why link to wikipedia?

Answer (score 0):

For new people reading this here's the relevant code section that finally solved everything which I am quoting from the msdn forums post above:

> Private Sub wb_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
>   System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles
>   wb.DocumentCompleted
>           ' Tabp.wb_DocumentCompleted   - Internet Related Document completion routine
>
> ```
>     If doc IsNot Nothing Then
>         If m_EditMode = True Then
>             doc.designMode = "On"
>         Else
>             doc.designMode = "Off"
>         End If
>     End If
>
>     If wb.Document IsNot Nothing Then HTMLDOC = wb.Document
>
>     If wb.CanGoBack Then
>         mbBack.ImageIndex = ImglstImages.cVLeftArrowQuiescent
>         mbBack.Enabled = True
>     Else
>         mbBack.ImageIndex = ImglstImages.cVLeftArrowGreyed
>         mbBack.Enabled = False
>     End If
>     If wb.CanGoForward Then
>         mbforward.Enabled = True
>         mbforward.ImageIndex = ImglstImages.cVRightArrowQuiescent
>     Else
>         mbforward.Enabled = False
>         mbforward.ImageIndex = ImglstImages.cVRightArrowGreyed
>     End If
>     wb.AllowNavigation = False
>     cmbxAddressbar.Text = wb.Url.ToString
>     AddIfUnique(cmbxAddressbar.Text)
>     If Form1.GetClassIdentifier = m_ClassIdentifier Then Form1.ProgBar.Visible = False
>     wb.AllowNavigation = True
>     PU.Clear() '''''
>     wb.Focus()
> End Sub
> ```

This is all I have that address's the question. To conclude their were two main problems with the code this was used for:

1. The html editing feature was disabled on windows 7 sp1 prohibiting usage (before the below answer the original author I was helping failed to correctly code his/her HTML editor).
2. The original author of the code did not include a document_completed event making the code before fail to work correctly in the new windows 7 sp1 environment.
   Note: this is a personal coding project and yes the author gave me permission to use the code and/or edit it as desired.
   Note: this is the orginal answer from above used. I wanted to show my code so everyone did not think I was doing this out of thin air.